# Being Religious vs Being Spiritual

Tags: scripture, vedas, gods, spirituality

We sometimes hear people claiming to be spiritual over religious. What is the difference between 'Being Religious' and 'Being Spiritual' as per the Scriptures?

Comment: 'Being spiritual but not religious' is a phenomenon found exclusively in white societies. Such people do believe in a higher entity but refuse to be a part of any religious denomination due various socio-economic factors. Our scriptures don't recognize such a difference.

Comment: This is  good question not sure why it is being downvoted .. Religiousness is more a thing to show off through visible signs and symbols .. for example if we find someone with the name Swami we will assume that he is a saint but internally that person might be far from being one, same with dress and attire .. for example i we find a person dressed li saffron clothes endowed with tilak and sandal paste on forejhead and wearing malas etc. we will immediately assume that he is a saint but again internally that person might not have the traits of a saint

Comment: Spirituality is that internal thing that do not depend on external symbols.

Answer (score 0):

As this is a forum on Hinduism, the question can only be answered from a Hindu definition. Any answer which might answer it from any other religious or sociological perspective are irrelevant. Scripture defines an individual's tendencies as sattva, rajas, and tamas.

Sri Krishna addresses this in the *Bhagavad Gita* Chapter 17. The Divine Lord says in *Gita* 17 (Swami Nikhilananda translator):

> 3. The faith of each man is in accordance with his natural disposition. A man, O Bharata, is made of his faith; what is faith is, that verily he is.
>
> (*Nikhilananda footnotes the word 'faith' with the following: The untranslatable Sanskrit word "sraddha" denotes an intuitive conviction in the existence of Truth and also a mental attitude, on the part of the aspirant, consisting primarily of sincerity of purpose, humility, and reverence.*)
>
> 4. Men in whom sattva previals worship the gods; men in whom rajas prevails worship demigods and demons, and men whom tamas prevails worship ghosts and disembodied spirits.
>
> ...
> 11. That sacrifice is of the nature of sattva which is offered according to scriptural rules by those who expect no reward and who firmly believe that it is their duty to to sacrifice.
>
> 12. But that sacrifice which is performed in expectation of reward and for the sake of ostentation--know that to be of the nature of rajas.
> 13. But that sacrifice which is not performed according to the scriptural rules, and in which no food is distributed, no hymns are chanted, and no fees paid, and which is devoid of faith, is said to be of the nature of tamas.

You may read Chapter 17 for further clarifications of the distinctions between sattva, rajas, and tamas by the Lord...it should be apparent that those whose worship is of the nature of rajas and tamas are 'religious' and those whose worship is 'spiritual' are sattva. The three pronged definition of religious characteristics defined in the Upanishads and spoken by Sri Krishna much more adequately defines human characteristics than the bipolar
'religious or spiritual'.

Comment: I don't see how it is apparent that "spiritual" is sattva. Besides from your selective out of place translations it seems those worshiping ghosts are tamasic and they in turn are "religious"